# Restrict allowed users when using client certificates

Tags: nginx

In our corporate network, all users have client certificates deployed. So when I use the "ssl_verify_client: on;" directive, all users are granted access.

How can I restrict access to a list of valid users, eg. only the IT-Department. I would like to have a file, similar to a htpassword file, that contains the usernames that are allowed to access the application.

How is this possible in nginx?

Comment: You could check `$ssl_client_s_dn`/`$ssl_client_i_dn` variables.

Comment: @alexey-ten  I can the  $ssl_client_s_dn within a **if** directive, but I would need a single "if" for every user or a regex like /foo|bar|acme/. Neither one "feels righ". I am looking for something like a "valid-users" directive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `$ssl_client_s_dn` with `map` directive:

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $access_denied {
    default 1;
    "alice" 0;
    "bob"   0;
}
```

and check it with `if`

```
if ($access_denied) {
    return 403;
}
```